# How to assign to env in loop inside Jenkins declarative pipeline script block

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a problem assigning to the `env` variable in loop. I basically want to copy everything from user input form to env:

```
for (elem in userInput)
  env["${elem.key}"] = "${elem.value}"
```

however this fails with:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods putAt java.lang.Object java.lang.String java.lang.Object
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectStaticMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:189)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onSetArray(SandboxInterceptor.java:474)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$11.call(Checker.java:438)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedSetArray(Checker.java:445)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.setArray(SandboxInvoker.java:49)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ArrayAccessBlock.rawSet(ArrayAccessBlock.java:26)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:120)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    ...
```

Assigning this way works:

```
env.KEY1 = userInput['KEY1']
env.KEY2 = userInput['KEY2']
```

However I'd still prefer to update the `env` in a loop to avoid duplication and possibility of typos, is there any way to do that/merge with the input data somehow?
(and yes, the pipeline is declarative, running in a sandbox and it should remain as such)

Comment: Probably failing because your script is running in a sandbox. Can you clear the execute in sandbox checkbox?

Comment: Or can you side-step it with `env."${elem.key}" = elem.value`?

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks! Even with `env."${elem.key}" = elem.value`. I'm still pretty new in groovy, didn't know that such syntax is possible :)

Answer (score 6):

Approve `putAt` method in the [sandbox](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/).

Alternatives can be

```
env.put(elem.key, elem.value)
env."${elem.key}" = elem.value
```

Also never use double quotes in this syntax `env["key"]`. Because `env["key"]` and `env['key']` are two different keys. In your example you'd better go with just `env[elem.key]` or `env[elem.key.toString()]` if `elem.key` may not be a string. See [Why Map does not work for GString in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39173688/4624905)