# Why I cannot get exactly the same GString as was put to map in Groovy?

Tags: dictionary, groovy, gstring

With the following snippet I cannot retrieve `gString` from a map:

```
def contents = "contents"
def gString = "$contents"

def map = [(gString): true]

assert map.size() == 1 // Passes
assert gString.hashCode() == map.keySet().first().hashCode() // Passes, same hash code
assert gString.is(map.keySet().first()) // Passes, exactly the same object
assert map[gString] // Fails
```

**How is that possible?**

What's interesting here is that `map.get(map.keySet()[0])` works fine while `map.get[map.keySet()[0]]` does not.

Assertion message clearly shows that there's something wrong:

```
assert map[gString] // Fails
       |  ||
       |  |contents
       |  null
       [contents:true]
```

It's not the same question as [Why groovy does not see some values in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705492/why-groovy-does-not-see-some-values-in-dictionary)
First answer there suggests:

> You're adding GString instances as keys in your map, then searching for them using String instances.

In this question I clearly add `GString` and try to retrieve `GString`.

Also neither [Why are there different behaviors for the ways of addressing GString keys in maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713359/why-are-there-different-behaviors-for-the-ways-of-addressing-gstring-keys-in-map) nor [Groovy different results on using equals() and == on a GStringImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682206/groovy-different-results-on-using-equals-and-on-a-gstringimpl) have an answer for me. I do not mutate anything and I do not mix `String` with `GString`. [Groovy documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes) is not helpful as well.

Comment: Very good question, maybe you should add to the ticket that `map.get[map.keySet()[0]]` does not work, but `map.get(map.keySet()[0])` works fine.

Comment: @Vampire thanks, edited question - indeed very interesting

Comment: Just adding that doing `map[gString] = 1;` results in this interesting map `[contents:true, contents:1]`. Almost as if `getAt`/`putAt` use string representation of gStrings...

Comment: Please see my comments on your (incorrectly sidelined) question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141245/why-map-does-not-work-for-gstring-in-groovy . You seem to have found a legitimate bug. Groovy runtime seems to be dynamically mapping ```map[gString]``` to the wrong overload of ```DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt()```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You seem to have discovered a bug in Groovy's runtime argument overloading evaluation.

**Answer:**

`map[gString]` is evaluated as `map.getAt(gString)` at runtime straightforwardly via Groovy's operator overloading mechanism. So far, so good, but now is where everything starts to go awry. The Java `LinkedHashMap` class does not have a `getAt` method anywhere in it's type hierarchy, so Groovy must use dynamically associated mixin methods instead (Actually that statement is sort of reversed. Groovy uses mixin methods *before* using the declared methods in the class hierarchy.)

So, to make a long story short, Groovy resolves `map.getAt(gString)` to use the category method `DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt()`. Easy-peasy, right? Except that this method has a large number of different argument overloads, several of which might apply, especially when you take Groovy's default argument coercion into account.

Unfortunately, instead of choosing `DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt(Map<K,V>,K)`, which would seem to be a perfect match, Groovy chooses `DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt(Object,String)`, which coerces the `GString` key argument into a `String`. Since the actual key is in fact a `GString`, the method ultimately fails to find the value.

To me the real killer is that if the argument overload resolution is performed directly from code (instead of after the operator resolution and the category method selection), then Groovy makes the right overload choice! That is to say, if you replace this expression:

```
map[gString]
```

with this expression:

```
DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt(map,gString)
```

then the argument overloading is resolved *correctly*, and the correct value is found and returned.